# Find files and display results in an specific format to txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I currently have many text files over several directories that I am sorting and storing the results in text file. The issues is not the sorting part but formatting the output that gets placed in the text file. I am looking to output in this format `file '/path/to/file1'` currently it shows `/path/to/file1`. I want to do this all within one process(not have to run an additional loop or fine to change the format).

```
$ target=~/tmp/shuf
$ destination=/filepath/
$ find $target -iname "*.txt" -type f | shuf | awk -F- '{printf("%s:%s\n", $0, $NF)}' | sort -t : -k 2 -s | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs -n1 basename | sed "s,^,$destination," > $destination/results.txt
```

Current results.txt:

```
/path/to/cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt
/path/to/s630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt
```

Desired results.txt:

```
file '/path/to/cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt'
file '/path/to/s630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt'
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that, though? Single quote is no safer than space or newline (or slash!) as a filename delimiter; all of these are allowed characters in filenames. If you want a really safe delimiter, use a literal null byte. But this reeks of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @tripleee the `result.txt` has to be in that specific format `file 'blah/blah.txt'` because it is required by an additional script(not related to this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find `awk` is often easier for this kind of formatting, if you don't have substitutions. This also allows us to skip the basename call and leave that part to `awk` as well. Just note that this will not work if you have any forward slashes in your actual filenames.

```
find $target -type f -iname "*.txt" \
 | shuf \
 | awk -F- '{printf("%s:%s\n", $0, $NF)}' \
 | sort -t : -k 2 -s \
 | cut -d : -f 1 \
 | awk -F / '{printf("file '\''%s'\''\n", $0)}' \
 > $destination/results.txt
```

Comment: Great, but wait, the rest `| xargs -n1 basename | sed "s,^,$destination," > $destination/results.txt`?

Comment: The awk replaces the basename and the sed. You just need to add in the redirect (everything from ">") to get it in the file again. I've added to the answer.

Comment: Great, everything is squashed together. where could i insert `\n` for a new line for each `file 'file/to/path/something-001.txt'`

Comment: This also picking up all files not just the `.txt` files. I just want to limit it to text files.

Comment: Hmm it is still not placing it in a new line

Comment: I've reformatted so you can see what is happening a bit clearer. There is definitely a newline in the last `printf` (at the end of the format string in the second last line). Works fine on my side. Perhaps the unix newlines aren't working in Notepad? Try to `cat` the file or to open it in Wordpad.

Comment: You were right the `\n` showed in wordpad. The source path of the files are not shown in the results.txt

Comment: Done. I assume you will remember about the date formatting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63322/discussion-between-techaddict82-and-chthonicdaemon).

Comment: Chat doesn't seem to be loading.

Comment: Remember how the files came from their respective folders? I am trying to add that to the result `file '/semester_1/cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt'`

Comment: Done. You should be able to spot the patterns now to change the rest to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, correct making the changes. Sorry for being a hassle. I am feeding this file into another script that is why the format needs to be specific. I need the full path `file /media/sf_sandbox/files/semester_1/cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt'`

Comment: Edited, but if your goal is to call file on all the files in this particular order, you may be better off skipping the last two lines and just using `| xargs -n1 file` instead.

Comment: Ok this works now. But do you mean take out the last `cut` and `awk` and replace with `| xargs -n1 file`

Comment: No, I mean the awk and the redirect. But if this works, just accept this answer and ask a new question if you have further questions.